# Ajax request, how to call an other function than "success" one's?

Tags: ajax, jquery

I use JQuery Ajax function :

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    success: function (){
        ...
    },
    ...
});
```

I need to execute some code just before every call of the `success` function (but after the response has been received). 
I suppose that this `success` function is triggered like an event, so **is there a way to make an other function call in place of `success` one's?**

Comment: you could just call that function with the first statement in done

Comment: Have you tried beforeSend?

Comment: @AndyHolmes no I never used it, but actually the code I want to execute just before the done callback has to manipulate the response content, so I thought the beforeSend function wasn't able to do it, isn't it?

Comment: Ah that makes a bit more sense now you've explained your needs more. Yes you're right, the beforeSend executes code before the ajax call is sent to the php, hence it's name. Looks like you need to run a custom function inside the success function of ajax to trigger what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed in calling an other function just before success one by replacing `$.ajax()` by a custom function like :

```
function mYajax(options) {
    var temporaryVariable = options.success;

    options.success = function () {
        console.log('Custom')
        if (typeof temporaryVariable === 'function')
            temporaryVariable()
    };
    return $.ajax(options);
}

$('button').click(function () {
    mYajax({
        url: "/echo/json/",
        data: {
            foo: "bar"
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log('succeed action');
        },

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) methods to do this.

Sounds like you might want to use [AjaxComplete](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/):

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
    // do something here when ajax calls complete
});
```

Be warned -- this will occur for EVERY jQuery ajax call on the page...

Comment: @AndyHolmes sorry bad cut and paste. Updated and fixed.

Comment: I've made some tests, but `ajaxComplete` is called after `success`or `error` handler isn't it?

Comment: No. But I guess the question is now what are you actually trying to do. Why do you need to always manipulate the response from the server?

Comment: Actually I'm improving a website which have hundred of ajax request. I have to add in every ajax request a security check (contained into the response json) in order to decide if I continue the `success` callback or if I show a warning. I asked this question because I think I could do something with it and inheritance. I've also an other way: https://gist.github.com/Fractaliste/8620506

Answer (score 0):

You could also call that other function right at the biginning of done:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    done: function (){
        someOtherFunction();
    },
    ...
});
```

This should pretty much accomplish what you described in your question.

Comment: Thanks, but the aim of my question was in fact to avoid editing my hundred of done, success, error handlers as your proposition.

Answer (score 0):

Is beforeSend what you are looking for:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "...",
    beforeSend: function (x) {
        //do something before the the post/get
    }
}).done(function (data) {
    //done code
});
```

Comment: I don't say it in my question, but the code I want to execute just before the done callback has to manipulate the response content.

Comment: Oh I understand, I didn't get that from your question